# String matching in Python and IF command

Tags: python, string, if-statement, matching

I have a list of different names. I want to take one name at a time and match it with values in a particular column in a data frame. If the conditions are met, the following calculation will be performed:

```
orderno == orderno + 1
```

However, unfortunately, the code does not seem to work. Is there anything that I can do to make sure it works?

```
DfCustomers['orderno'] = 0
for i in uniquecustomer:
  if i == "DfCustomers['EntityName']":
        orderno == orderno + 1
```

Comment: `orderno == orderno + 1` is a comparison, not assignment.  You want `orderno = orderno + 1` (single equal sign).

Comment: Also, the double quotes around `"DfCustomers['EntityName']"` look suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes (""). By writing

```
if i == "DfCustomers['EntityName']":
```

you compare the variable i with the actual string "DfCustomers['EntityName']" instead of the variable DfCustomers['EntityName']. Try to remove the quotes and print out the variable to get a feeling for it, e.g.

```
print("DfCustomers['EntityName']")
```

vs

```
print(DfCustomers['EntityName'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first removing the quotes around the "DfCustomers['EntityName']" so as to not just compare directly to that string. Then, within your logic the orderno variable should be incremented by 1, not compared to its value + 1. The new code could look something like this:

```
DfCustomers['orderno'] = 0
for i in uniquecustomer:
  if i == DfCustomers['EntityName']:
        orderno = orderno + 1
```

Comment: Thanks! but when I do as you've suggested I get this error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Can you send across your full code? It would be easier to debug rather than trying to infer what you are trying to do. Are you trying to match to a particular value in the DfCustomers['EntityName'] column or check if the values in uniquecustomer are present in the DfCustomers['EntityName'] column?

Comment: This data is from a restaurant. 

uniquecustomers contains a list of all customers that have ever ordered. Whereas Dfcustomers contains details about the customer each time an order is placed. By creating orderno i'm trying to get a variable that notes the order no of the customer. This is done by going through each customer (from uniquecustomer) and matching them with the Dfcustomers database (via 'EntityName') and updating the value accordingly.